# Difference between (++i) and (i++)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In C++ I understand that `(++i)` should return a reference to `i` because the need of concatenation of operators, but what I can't figure out is:

Why `(i++)` should return `i` by value?

Can anyone please clarify.

Comment: Unless you are talking about a specific language, ++i always return the value, not a reference.

Comment: @all : I'm pretty sure this is fine as language-agnostic.  Is there any language that could return `i++` by reference?  It _must_ return a new value, in any language's implementation.

Comment: Based on the context of the question, I would assume he is talking about overloading the ++ operator in C++. A clarification of the question would be helpful.

Comment: 5ound, yes i am talking of c++, forgot to mention it.

Comment: @Stephen You see, to believe there is something god-given  about what i++ and ++i do. I can easily invent a language were one one prints "foo" and the other "bar". In fact I can do that in C++ for class types without inventing a new language.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth : fair point... but it's a bit of a strawman.

Comment: @Stephen No, it isn't. I do not understand the desire of people to answer questions here at the drop of a hat, without trying to get the questioner to explain their real problem in detail. Why rush in making assumptions?

Comment: @Neil: Because doing so you get the chance of earning some reputation ?

Comment: What does this have to do with operator-overloading [tag]?

Comment: @Johnsyweb perhaps because the question is about overloading the ++ operators?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`++i` can be written as

```
prefix_inc (this) {
   increase this by 1
   return this
}
```

Since the real `i` is returned, we can take reference of it. However, `i++` looks like

```
postfix_inc (this) {
   set old_this = copy of this
   increase this by 1
   return old_this
}
```

as `old_this` is just a local variable, the reference of it is pointless after `i++` is completed. So logically it should return an rvalue.

Answer (score 27):

`i++` returns a value because it is returns the *old* value of `i`, while `i` is increased by `1`.

A basic implementation of this would be:

```
int i++() {
  int old = i;
  i = i + 1;
  return old;
}
```

So, if it returned a reference, it would be *the wrong value*... since `i`'s value has been incremented!

Comment: Furthermore, it can't return a reference to `old`, because you can't return a reference (or pointer) to a temporary.

Answer (score 4):

Let `foo` be some function. `foo(i++)` calls `foo(i)` with the old value of `i` and increments `i`, hence the need to build a temporary copy. `foo(++i)` increments `i` and then calls `foo` with the incremented value, so for better performance we can reuse the same variable, no need to have a temporary copy.

Comment: `foo(i++)` increments `i` and _then_ calls `foo` with the original value of `i`. There's a sequence point between the evaluation of the parameter (with its side effect) and the function call.

Answer (score 2):

i++
This returns the value of the i before it is incremented. So the idea is that if you want to use i in a function, and then increment the value after using it, you can do that in one step.
As an example, here is how I would overload that operator for integers.

```
Integer Integer::operator++()
{
    Integer returnValue = *this;
    this->increment();
    return returnValue;
}
```

So it increments the value and then returns what it *used* to be. It also doesn't return a reference, because returning a reference would be different from what was originally passed, which would break cascading.

++i
This increments the value of i, and then returns the new value. So you could use this in a situation where you want to increment i and then use the new value in your function.

```
Integer Integer::operator++(Integer i)
{
    i.increment();
    return i;
}
```

So the value it returns is the incremented value of i.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
Console.Writeline(i++); // Output 0, after that, i will be 1


int x = 0;
Console.Writeline(++x); // Output 1
```

Note: code is in C#

Answer (score 0):

While prefix `++i` returns the incremented value and the suffix `i++` returns the old value and increments it afterwards the operator selection is significant if you care for the CPU cycles. Prefix increment is faster ;-)

Comment: Simplistic compilers can create a temporary variable to store the intermediate value. It does cost nothing for standard types like `int`but for eg. objects it can be costly. It matters if your app is CPU bound. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.15

Answer (score 0):

5 cents:

As a consequence of `i++` making a copy, it is slower for non-POD variables (i.e. iterators). You should use `++i` anywhere when possible.

I personaly always use `for(...;...;++i)` instead of `for(...;...;i++)`, although compiller should optimize that.

Answer (score -4):

If you're ever in a scenario where it matters, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: If you have to overload that operator, it matters that you understand how they work.

Comment: I wouldn't inflict ++i vs i++ on anyone that had to use my class.